# Add a counter in front of each event on FullCalendar or a total sum of events count in the day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a  `fullcalendar` implemented that gets the events feed from an ajax call and works properly. The problem is that I need to have a counter in front of each event for each day, or a total sum of events for each day next to the day number. For example I would like to have on my events fullcalendar table for each day:

```
    (3) 23 Oct
1# 10am Event1
2# 11am Event2
3# 12:30am Event3
```

next day would be like

```
    (2) 24 Oct
1# 12am Event1a
2# 13pm Event2b
```

I tried playing around with eventRender but as the events are getting rendered on different row on their tables I couldn't find a way to properly iterate through them.

The code so far:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    lang: 'el',
    draggable: false,
    events: {
        url: '<?= base_url(); ?>appointments/ajaxgetall',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching appointments!');
        },
        color: '#D7B4A3',
        textColor: 'white'
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.find(".fc-time").each(function(index) {
            element.find('.fc-time').prepend(index + " ");
        });
    },
    eventClick: function(rantebou, jsEvent, view) {
        if (rantebou.url) {
            window.open(rantebou.url, '_self');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

The php code for fetching the array of the events (ajaxgetall()):

```
$jsonArr = array(
    'id' => $entry['id'],
    'type' => $entry['app_type'],
    'title' => $entry['name'].
    " ".$entry['surname'].
    ". Office: ".$entry['app_office'].
    ". Title:".$entry['app_title'].
    ". Desc: ".$entry['app_description'],
    'start' => $entry['app_date'],
    'allDay' => false,
    'office' => $entry['app_office'],
    'description' => $entry['app_description'],
    'className' => 'event_'.$entry['app_type'],
    'url' => base_url().
    'appointments/editappointment/'.$entry['id']
);
```

Comment: use `events: function()` approach instead or string url. Then you will write your own ajax and have to do the calculations yourself.   See:  http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

Comment: Tweak this code to get all the events in a day instead of in a week: http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/555/